# Ubuntu server as a NAS, hot-swap and adding drives?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, nas, ubuntu-server

I'm thinking of buying a HP Proliant microserver to replace an old dusty laptop which I now use as a home server and a Netgear ReadyNASDuo which is not raided at the moment.

I want the server to replace my NAS and home server, so here some questions:

From what I understand I can't hot-swap, right?

I was thinking of having five drives in total but slowly upgrading it.
So I was going to start with two drives (one drive to drive the OS, and the other to have as future RAID). But since I want to plan ahead I would like to have RAID 5 (which means more storage than raid 1, when 4 drives are inserted, while everything is still backed up, right?).

Do I have to have 3 drives from the start to have a RAID 5?, or can I use/change to RAID 5 when three drives are added without actually formatting a drive?

I've looked if this is doable but did not find any info on it.

Can I even format one drive as a RAID and then add other drives?, or must I start with 4 drives from the start?

And any other tips on doing software raid on ubuntu would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the specification of HP Proliant microserver, it doesn't support hot swap.

You have to have at least 3 drives from the start for RAID 5.

You can increase the number of disk of RAID 5 by adding new drive without destroying existing data.

using `mdadm` as software raid is great. You can have more information from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=408461).

Comment: If I have a RAID 5 and three drives and want to add a fourth, I cannot do this by using mdadm?, and have the fourth drive be part of the raid5?

Comment: You could, but all data in the RAID will be destroyed if you change the RAID size. If you add the drive as a spare disk, no data would be destroyed. The spare disk would replace any failed disk have happend.

Comment: I've looked around and does not this article do that http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=517282

Comment: And this: http://www.allmyit.com.au/mdadm-growing-raid5-array-ubuntu

Comment: Yes. It is possible to use mdadm to grow raid.